# Format of Time with SQLAlchemy in Flask-Admin (and daterangepicker)

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, daterangepicker

Briefly speaking, I need the `'%M:%S'` format like '23:30'.

Is there any ways to:

1. Show exactly in `'%M:%S'` format instead of `'%H:%M:%S'` in the list page?
2. Pop up daterangepicker with `minute selector & second selector` instead of `hour selector & minute selector` in the edit page.

The following are my code but related to the question only:

```
class CustomAdminModelConverter(AdminModelConverter):
    @converts('Time')
    def convert_time(self, field_args, **extra):
        return TimeField(
                    formats=('%H:%M:%S', '%M:%S'), 
                    default_format='%M:%S',
                    **field_args
                )

class CustomModelView(ModelView):
     model_form_converter = CustomAdminModelConverter
```

The above are the Custom Classes I use.

```
pm_view = CustomModelView(Plus_Minus_Record, db.session)

# changes how the input is parsed by strptime (12 hour time)
pm_view.form_args = dict(
        clock_start=dict(format='%M:%S'),
        clock_end=dict(format='%M:%S')
    )
# changes how the DateTimeField displays the time
pm_view.form_widget_args = dict(
        clock_start={'data-date-format': u'mm:ss'},
        clock_end={'data-date-format': u'mm:ss'}
    )

admin.add_view(pm_view)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figure it out.

I post my solution here: 
https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/1210